# Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'JSON' in angular2 with rxjs5

Tags: json, angular, rxjs5

I want to change all of my EventEmitter to Subjects since it is the recommended way to share variables and states instead of emitting an event.

But now I've got a problem and I just don't understand how to solve it. Here is the sample code:

```
@Injectable()
export class TicketsService implements OnInit {
    private _url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/getAllTickets";
    private _refreshTickets:Subject<JSON> = new Subject<JSON>();
    public allTickets:JSON;

    private _url_postNewTicket = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/postNewTicket";    

    constructor(private _http:AuthHttp) {
        this.allTickets = this._refreshTickets
            .mergeMap(() => this._http.get(this._url))
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .cache();

    }

    refreshAllTickets() {
        console.log("refresh all tickets..");
        this._refreshTickets.next(null);
    }
}
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

> public/angular/app/tickets.service.ts(26,9): error TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'JSON'.
>   [1]   Property 'parse' is missing in type 'Observable'.

I guess I could write `allTickets:JSON` as `allTickets:any` but in the component I use **ngFor** to iterate - so I get the error from ngFor that it needs an array.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `allTickets` to be of type: `Observable<any>` and then in your **ngFor** binding you can use the async pipe like so:

```
*ngFor="let ticket of allTickets | async"
```

Comment: yes, it actually worked. such an obvious mistake...thanks =)